# Can't delete visible cache from Android 9+

Tags: android, caching, native

I want to develop an application that can delete Visible Cache from the directory "android/data/package_name/cache".

However, as far as I know, starting from Android version 9, the application is no longer granted permission to access this directory.

I have noticed that [CCleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.piriform.ccleaner&hl=vi&gl=US) can somehow delete this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION.

However, if you want to upload this app to the PlayStore you have to give an explicit document detailing why you need this functionality and this has to be approved by google for the app to be in the Playstore